# Google Chrome: Disable specific application from Call UI List

Tags: google-chrome, skype, skype-for-business

When I click on a number, the "Make a call from" UI pops up:

[image]

I used to have Skype for Business installed but not anymore (or at least it's not on my app list in Windows). Is there a way to specifically remove this application from popping up on the list?

Comment: Check in `chrome://extensions/` if you have the Skype extension still installed. Remove it if it's there.

Comment: @harrymc I dont have any extension related to it

Comment: Do you have Skype installed on an Android phone perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack but only way I could make this work.
Settings > Apps > Default apps > scroll down > Set defaults by app > Skype > Manage >  URL:tel > I set it to Chrome. It removed Skype from Make call from dialog.

[image]

Comment: Generic way (if you don't have Skype installed): Settings, Apps, Default Apps, scroll down then click **Chose default apps by protocol**, scroll down then click TEL (URL:tel)

Comment: Going to this registry location `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\tel` then deleting the subkey `UserChoice` does that same thing

Comment: Ding ding! This was the solution. Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 0):

Note that you might have installed *two* Skype versions. In *Settings > Apps* you may find "Skype" (UWP version) and also "Skype version x.xx" (desktop version).

From the article
[How do I completely remove Skype from my computer?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/how-do-i-completely-remove-skype-from-my-computer/d88e2ad5-62bb-4874-b56e-e101e5a16366)

[image]

---

You could also run PowerShell as Administrator and enter this command :

```
Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object {$_.Name -Match "skype"} | Remove-AppxPackage
```

Comment: Skype is not installed in any way. `Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object {$_.Name -Match "skype"}` returned nothing.